# Сделать запрос к бд с множественным join-ом

Tags: php, laravel, framework, eav

Имеется вот такая структура:
Attributes_group -> has many -> attributes -> has many -> attributes_value.
При добавлении товара вывожу все эти таблицы,и отмечаю нужные attributes_value. Они отправляются на сервер массивом. Выглядит это так:
[image: Скрин с характеристиками]

Как можно их обьединить с товаром, что бы потом в шаблоне можно было бы их вывести вот так:

```
foreach($product->attributes_group as $group){
    $group->name
    foreach($group->attributes as $attribute){
        $attribute->name
        foreach($attribute->value as $value){
            $value->val
        }
    }
}
```

upd: добавил таблицу ‘product_attribute‘. В этой таблице ид товара, и ид значения атрибута (который массивом отправляется на сервер).Но в шаблоне с товаром выводится только значение. Но оно и понятно почему. А вот как обьединить товары с характеристиками что б вышло так - Product->Attribute_group->attribute->attribute_value не знаю.

Comment: А вы хоть какой-нибудь join попытались сделать?

Comment: @ConnorHolt да пробовал. Сейчас сделал так (но это совсем не правильно): добавил таблицу ‘product_attribute‘. В этой таблице ид товара, и ид значения атрибута (который массивом отправляется на сервер).Но в шаблоне с товаром выводится только значение. Но оно и понятно почему. А вот как обьединить товары с характеристиками что б вышло так - Product->Attribute_group->attribute->attribute_value не знаю

Answer (score 0):

```
Product::with('attributes_group', 'attributes_group.attributes', 'attributes_group.attributes.attributes_value')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

P.S. Нижнее подчеркивание в названии модели/таблицы уберите и поменяйте на AttributesGroup

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Но такой запрос не выйдит, т.к. в пивотной таблице 'product_attributes' только product_id  и attribute_value_id. Получается наоборот. Тоесть, сначала выведутся все значения атрибутов, потом сами атрибуты,а потом группы атрибутов. А надо наоборот)

Comment: Можно сделать селект и потом перегруппировать в нужный массив как вариант

Comment: можно увидеть пример реализации? Просто я не совсем понимаю как это сделать.